# How to insert Array formula to excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula

```
Sheet1.Range("P7").FormulaArray = "=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A$1:A8,A8)=COUNTIF(A:A,A8),COUNTIF(A:A,A8)>=1),"Completed","")"
```

I am getting a syntax error in VBA using this not sure why. How are array formulas supposed to be written?

Comment: You need to double up the quotes within the formula, see the linked duplicate.

Comment: @BigBen Great cheers!